# Grammatical rule used in "change it will" in the following sentence

Tags: subject-verb-inversion

The sentence is:

> That's why the future Internet will have to change, and **change it will**.

This looks like a kind of an inverted sentence but I didn't see such a structure before in the explanations given for inverted sentences from the websites which I looked at.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's still "inversion."

We can use **inversion for emphasis** as in the given sentence.

The emphasis has shifted from *it* to *change* by the inversion, moving *change* to the front of the clause: *change it will*.

> That's why the future Internet will have to change, and change it will.

=

> That's why the future Internet will have to change, and it will change (**for sure**).

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I was unable to give an upvote to your answer as I'm new here. I hope somebody does on behalf of me.

Comment: That's okay, it's nice to be of help all the same.